# Mobile first 7.1 push notification

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

While implementing push notification in the mobile first application in which IMC(IBM Mobile Client) is also integrated do we need to anything extra?

Comment: Where is the IBM Mobile Client installed? In the server ? In the client device? How did you integrate? What is the purpose ? What are you trying to acheive?

Comment: Thanks for your reply...Client is installed on Mobile device and user is logged in outside the IBM network. ....our requirement is to show the push notification on iOS and Android device. Now we are able to receive the notification for Android but in case of iOS we are getting the below error

Comment: [9/2/16 7:36:37:504 CDT] 00000186 ApnsConnectio E com.ibm.pushworks.server.notification.apns.ApnsConnectionImpl sendMessage Couldn't send message after 3 retries.Message(Id=1; Token=A7A47E182B13F71D4715312D1578F0B11863E2E6F1CD570C62513F5CDC5F3DD0; Payload={"aps":{"alert":{"body":"MySA Test Notification2","action-loc-key":null},"sound":"","badge":1},"payload":"{\"alias\":\"myPush\",\"custom\":\"data\"}"})
                                 javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: com.ibm.jsse2.util.j: End user tried to act as a CA
 at com.ibm.jsse2.j.a(j.java:23)